# How to add skip rule in Publish Channels in Maximo

Tags: maximo

I have to add skip rule in publish channels like if route is not null then I have to send Task Work Orders and if job plan alone there then we need to send only parent workorder.
How can I add skip rule for above condition?

Answer (score 0):

You should review the [Rule Based Customisation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLKT6_7.6.0/com.ibm.mt.doc/gp_intfrmwk/c_ctr_custom_proc_rules.html) documentation for Integration Data Processing.